# What's a good credit score for my age?

Tags: united-states, credit-score

I only started building credit within the last three years, and I'm just now starting to get into situations where having good credit would be important. As a 26 year old, I have to ask, does age take into account for credit scores? I have noticed through the use of Credit Karma that they monitor how long you have been building credit, but beyond that does my actual age mean anything? Also for someone at the point I have described, what would be considered a pretty good credit score?

As a second little bonus question, how could I go about making my credit score go up?

EDIT: Currently I sit between 690 and 710 depending on the company.

Comment: What is your credit score now?

Comment: Sorry, didn't see this question for some reason, edited answer into the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Age doesn't signify, except that being younger means you have a shorter credit history by definition.

Re what affects credit score: [See many past answers here](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/credit-score). Basically, the obvious: demonstrating you can (or can't) be trusted to handle credit responsibly. That's what the score is trying to measure and predict, after all.

If you are careful with your money, that will already put you well above the average, and the credit score will look after itself. You really don't have to worry much about it until you start borrowing stupidly or fail to make most payments on time or otherwise give folks reason to worry about your willingness and ability to pay.

Comment: added link to the "See many past answers here" to get to credit tagged posts, in case that wasn't obvious.

Answer (score 0):

After you reach majority, and can legally enter into a contract, your age has no direct effect on your ability to borrow.  Your credit history shows account ages.  These are one of many factors which affect lender decisions.  Borrower age is not a factor on these decisions and is not a variable in the rating systems.

Your accounts' ages, and length of credit history DO have an effect.

For building credit rating:  research this on the internet.  Any 'system' or recommendation that involves carrying any balance on revolving credit account is wrong and should be dismissed.  Always pay your bills.  If you use a credit card, pay it in full each billing cycle.  Credit card industry uses rates which would have been considered usury not that long ago.